# requestedExecutionLevel level=requireAdministrator Forces app to run in new window

Tags: c#, windows, user-permissions

I have a program intended to be run in Command Prompt, that needs to require admin privileges.

I have `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` in my app.manifest file to make it require admin privileges. When this is set however, and I run `MyApp.exe` from a command prompt window, it runs the program in a new command prompt window (after asking for elevated access of course). If I take `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` out of my app.manifest it runs in the same window.

I need `MyApp.exe` to run in the same command prompt window I used to execute it while also requiring admin privileges. Is there a way to get this behavior?

Comment: My understanding is that administrator programs need to run in a different "desktop", which is the Windows abstraction for a group of windows that can talk to one another. To run in a different desktop, obviously, it needs a different window. If the program ran in the same desktop, it would be possible to use WinApi calls to access the windows and read their contents or tamper with it, which could be very bad. Short of running your command prompt as an administrator, I don't think you can have it in the same window.

Comment: @zneak: no, elevated processes don't run on a separate desktop.  (Only one desktop is shown to the user at a time, so that wouldn't work well.)

Comment: It should be possible to do that, but it isn't straightforward. You'd need three executables; first, a command-line executable that runs without elevation (that's the one you would call `myApp.exe` and reference from the command line). It would launch a GUI executable that runs with elevation, and wait for it to exit.  The GUI executable would attach to the parent console with AttachConsole() and then launch the command-line elevated executable that does the actual work.  You should probably also change the console title to make it visually obvious that it now has admin privilege.

Comment: @HarryJohnston is it "just" process permissions that prevent you from getting an admin window handle and messing with it then?

Comment: @zneak: no, integrity levels are the primary defense against GUI attacks.  A non-elevated process runs at medium integrity, so it can't send window messages to an elevated process (which runs at high integrity).